# What does this mean in the context of Stochastic Calculus?

Tags: stochastic-processes, notation, stochastic-calculus

I've reading into some Stochastic Calculus books and I've been stumped by two concepts used recurringly in the book. The first is a subscripted 1 which appears in the definition of a simple process (and in many other places as well) and having the expectation of the quotient of random processes with the filtrations E[Xs/Fs]. Could someone explain to me what these two things mean and give some rough definition to grasp the concept?

Comment: Source, please.

Comment: I've been reading from lecture notes. The book is squvietnam.pdf, you can find it on google.

Comment: http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~pontier/SquVietnam.pdf

Comment: Oh I thought you meant there was a 1 in the subscript. A 1 with a subscript in the context of probability is almost always an indicator function.

Comment: Thank you! And sorry if I confused you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a quotient of the process with filtration, it's almost certainly a conditional expectation. I recomend you get a more elementary book if you aren't familiar with the concept but your text presumes you are.

Subscripts have too many uses to be able to tell you what the author means without context.

Comment: http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2008/REUPapers/Olson.pdf look into the link and definition 3.1. It uses the subscripted 1 I'm speaking about. Couñd you refer me to some elementary book on the topic?

Comment: For finance a good elementary text is the one by Shreve. Vol 2 deals with continuous time.